# Adding values based on certain Data in a Colimn

Tags: sql

I have not been able to find anything on the web

I have 3 columns like so:

```
 Customer       Currency         Balance
|  a     |      |   AUD |       |  22.5    |      
|  b     |      |   GBP |       |  30.0    |      
|  c     |      |   GBP |       |  45.5    |      
|  d     |      |   USD |       |  56.9    |      
|  e     |      |   USD |       |  45.4    |      
|  f     |      |   EUR |       |  28.0    |
```

I want to get a full Sum of each currency, For example: so all the balances whose currecy is GBP, add them together and so on

Im new to SQL and again, i could not find anything online that does this

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Currency, SUM(Balance) AS total
FROM currencies
GROUP BY Currency
```

Comment: The only time anyone beats @Gordon to an answer is when he doesn't want to answer :-)

Comment: Well i blinked and all of a sudden, there was an answer! i cant accept for another 6 minutes but i will

Thanks for a hasty response

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code this is working fine with SQL Server 2012

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Customer Varchar(20),Currency varchar(20),Balance float)
INSERT @table
(Customer,Currency,Balance)
VALUES
('a','AUD',22.5),    
('b','GBP',30.0),    
('c','GBP',45.5),    
('d','USD',56.9),    
('e','USD',45.4),    
('f','EUR',28.0)

SELECT 
    Currency, Sum(Balance) AS Total
FROM 
    @table
GROUP BY 
    Currency
```